# SFTP createReadStream not writing into s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ssh, aws-lambda, sftp

I'm trying to read a file from an sftp server and stream that file into an s3 bucket. I'm not able to stream the file into the s3 bucket. Yes the file path is exactly correct. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. When I run the code, it doesn't even try to upload the stream into the bucket because I don't get any upload console logs.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const Client = require('ssh2').Client;
const conn = new Client();

const connSettings = {
    host: event.serverHost,
    port: event.port,
    username: event.username,
    password: event.password
};

exports.handler = function(event) {
    conn.on('ready', function() {
        conn.sftp(function(err, sftp) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Errror in connection", err);
                conn.end()
            } else {
                console.log("Connection established");

                let readStream = sftp.createReadStream(remoteFilePath);
                  console.log(`Read Stream ${readStream}`)
                  // readStream outputs [object Object] to the console

                const uploadParams = {
                    Bucket: s3Bucket,
                    Key: 'fileName',
                    Body: readStream
                }

                s3.upload (uploadParams, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error", err);
                    } if (data) {
                        console.log("Upload Success", data.Location);
                    }
                });

                conn.end()   
            }
        });
    }).connect(connSettings);
}
```

I want to be able to stream the readStream from sftp server into s3 bucket.

Comment: Can you narrow down the issue?  Setting S3 aside, does your read stream work if you dump it to the console?

Comment: @Brad Here's the output from my readStream when I do a console log``` Read Stream [object Object] ````

Comment: Try getting data from it though, to ensure it's working.  `readStream.on('readable', ...)`  https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_readable

Comment: I tried that and when the function executes, it doesn't print anything of the console logs. I think the issue is coming from the createReadStream.

Comment: You're saying that `readable` is firing?  Or, it isn't?  In any case, yes, it sounds like you've narrowed this down to your readable stream.  You should edit your question with just the relevant code needed to reproduce that specific problem... you might get a better answer.

Comment: @Brad the `readable` is not firing. I will edit the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`conn.end()` ends the connection immediately. Move that to *inside* your `s3.upload()` callback so that your data actually gets transferred before the connection is closed.

Comment: Thank you @mscdex. That fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

This is a working Node 12 example of what I believe you are trying to accomplish:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const Client = require('ssh2').Client;
const conn = new Client();
const { PassThrough } = require('stream');

conn.on('ready', () => {

    conn.sftp((err, sftp) => {

        const transferStream = new PassThrough();

        s3.upload({
            Bucket: s3Bucket,
            Key: 'test_file.txt',
            Body: transferStream
        }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(`Upload error: ${err}`);
            }
            if (data) {
                console.log(`Uploaded to [${data.Location}].`);
            }
        });

        sftp.createReadStream(remoteFilePath)
            .pipe(transferStream)
            .on('end', () => {
                transferStream.end();
                conn.end();
            });

    });

}).connect(connectionSettings);
```